# vb6, on key up event, different key code with different keyboard

Tags: vb6, onkeyup

In vb 6 on key up event, when i use laptop keyboard it will give proper key code value but when i connect external keyboard then the results was different key code value, is there any solution and why this is happening?

Comment: Is it all keys or particular keys? Can you give examples?

Comment: Perhaps Num Lock is on? Also note that "1" on the typewriter keys and "1" on the numeric keypad are returned as different keycodes.